# Not work RewriteCond in file .htaccess when write rule for many index file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When i make a request "http://domain/index.php" or such "http://domain" i want the server to give me 404 code. When i make "http://domain/some-path/index.php" i want the server to give me an index file from the "some-path" directory. But server give me 404 code in all cases. There my code in htaccsess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-path/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]

RewriteRule ^some-path\/(([^.]+\.(html|php))|(assets\/.*))$ /$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^some-path\/([^/.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

It seems that the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.html$` does not work correctly.

Comment: Now which one is it, `index.html` or `index.php`?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^some-path\/(([^.]+\.(html|php))|(assets\/.*))$ /$1 [L]` - this will rewrite `/some-path/index.php` to `/index.php`. So that does not match your stated requirement, _"i want the server to give me an index file from the "some-path" directory."_

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know you have never accepted any answer. Give it sometime when you see answer(s) you could let answerer know how it went. Now also you could go to old answers and accept applicable answers. It will help visitors to see which answer was helpful for question poster, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file.

- Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
- Also make sure to keep your .html files along side with your .htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index\.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?some-path/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]

RewriteRule ^some-path\/(([^.]+\.(html|php))|(assets\/.*))$ /$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^some-path\/([^/.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?!.*(some-path|robots\.txt)).*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^some-path/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]

RewriteRule ^some-path\/(([^.]+\.(html|php))|(assets\/.*))$ /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^some-path\/([^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^some-path\/([^/.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```